# What does return (pset[i]==i)? i:(pset[i]=findSet(pset[i])); mean?

Tags: c++, graph, kruskals-algorithm

I'm implementing the Kruskal algorithm and I found this code:

```
   int findSet(int i)
   {
    return (pset[i]==i)? i:(pset[i]=findSet(pset[i]));
   }
```

and I dont know what really mean, any help please? :)

Answer (score 2):

The `?:`is the [conditional operator in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx). It's equivalent to an `if-then-else` statement.  So this code is equivalent to:

```
int findSet(int i)
{
    if (pset[i]==i)
    { 
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        pset[i]=findSet(pset[i]));
        return pset[i];
    }
}
```

Within Kruskal's algorithm, this finds the set representartive of its argument (i.e. the root of its ancestry tree)

Answer (score 1):

I think the ternary operator(?:) is confusing you, lets replace it with if-else

```
int findSet(int i)
{
  if (pset[i]==i)
    return i;
  else 
  {
    pset[i]=findSet(pset[i]);
    return pset[i];
  }      
}
```

Hope now its more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [find union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) algorithm implementation (find method).

For example
pset is the array with indexes of parents for example:
pset[] = { 0, 2, 3, 0 }

So we know that parent of index 1 (pset[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)) is 2, parent of 2 is 3 parent of 3 is 0 and 0 is the root (because `parent[0] == 0`, more general `parent[i] == i` ).
The algorithm find(i) always returns the root value, so in this example always 0.
In this algorithm when we find the root then `(pset[i]==i) ? i` is true and i is returned, otherwise we traverse through the structure by execution:

```
pset[i]=findSet(pset[i]));
```

The assignment is to speed up next query find(i);
Read some articles about disjoint set data structure.